# Displaying more than one image on Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created an Android App that contains 10 TextView boxes and I have given each one a different background. When I run the app on my device, it crashes, if I use 10 different backgrounds. If I use only 8 different backgrounds to fill up the 10 TextView boxes, the app works fine. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
Sorry for not adding code, but below is the xml file. Notice I add a background to each TextView from img1 to img10. If I load this on my device, the program will crash. If I changed img9 to img7 and img10 to img7, then it will work fine. I cannot figure out why this occurs and I checked the sizes. They do not add up to 16MB.

So, excuse my ignorance. I am new to android app creating, but I found that a OutOfMemory exception is being thrown. This does not make size, b/c my images are all under 100 KB.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8ad0e8"
    tools:context=".Adamantium1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:background="@drawable/img1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img2"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img5"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img6"
            android:text="9" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img7"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img8"
            android:text="9" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/img9"
            android:text="7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="1"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/img10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EnterPass"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Enter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: please post the code, I am mindboggled

Comment: Search for "android bitmap out of memory"

Answer (score 1):

May be your images are too large to be held in the heap of per application in android which is 16 MB in 4.2 . 
Possible solution is decrease your image size. 
This is the best I can tell from your problem posted here.